# Getting all objects belonging to a class

Tags: java, android, reflection

I come from a Ruby on Rails background and started doing some Android programming.

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all objects in a class using Java.

In Rails you can do something like Building.all  and it'll return an array of  all created buildings

Is there something like that in Java?

If so, can you post a little example that would return an array of building objects for a Building class?

Comment: There are a few possibly workable solutions below, but this isn't really something that Java is intended to do.  If you tell us what you are trying to accomplish by doing so, we may be able to give you the right way to do it in Java.

Answer (score 3):

No. But if you want to have such a list, you can fill it yourself:

```
private static final Set<WeakReference<Building>> instances = 
       Setes.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<WeakReference<Building>>());

public Building() {
     synchronized(Building.class) {
         instances.add(new WeakReference(this));
     }
}

// etc the same in all constructors
```

`Sets.newSetFromMap(..)` is from the guava-libraries. If you don't want to use them, you can simply use the `Map` and `put(this, Boolean.TRUE)`

`WeakReference` means that the objects will be garbage-collected if they are not used anywhere else. `IdentifyHashMap` means that it does not matter whether you override `hashCode()` and `equals()`, your map will be filled with distinct instances. (thanks to Luke Hutteman for these improvements)

It is arguable whether this should be achieved in such a way. I would say that whoever creates instances can hold references to them, and not the class itself.

Comment: This is a valid solution, but the answer is not no.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler You guys are solving 2 different problems.  He is showing how to get all instances of a particular class.  You are showing how to use reflection to get information on the class.  Not sure which the op wanted, but I don't think the first thing is solvable with reflection.

Comment: @Mayra: it seems to me (dunno what Building.all is in Ruby) that OP wants all the attributes in a class, like `dir(class)` would do in Python

Comment: Building was just an example of a class.

Comment: You'll probably want to use a WeakHashMap instead; storing every created Building in a HashSet means these objects will never be garbage collected otherwise.

Comment: Another potential problem is that HashSets are based on equals/hashcode, and there may be multiple instances that are considered equal; also, unless Building is immutable, its hashcode may change after construction, causing it to be indexed incorrectly in the HashSet. You'd really need an IdentityHashMap to fix this, but then there's the memory leak issue again. I guess a custom solution that combines an IdentityHashMap with WeakReferences is necessary here.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not quite as simple as that since empty WeakReferences will need to be pruned from the collection at some point. What's really needed is a WeakIdentityHashSet but unfortunately no such class exists in the base Java libraries. Googling for it does turn up several hits though, which may be a starting point if this functionality is absolutely necessary. I agree that this approach is questionable though, and whoever creates these instances should probably be the one to be responsible for managing the references to them.

Answer (score 2):

`Building.all` only works in Rails because a class is also the entry point for ActiveRecord object-relational queries.  When you say `Building.all`, it's running a SQL query to pull all of the building objects out of the Buildings table.

So the real equivalent in Java is to use an ORM tool that uses the Active Record pattern.  There are a few, such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/), but none that has really caught on that I can find.  No idea if it's usable with Android.

Is Grails usable with Android?  If you want to get back into your Rails comfort zone, but in the JVM world, that's your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Luis, when in Rails you call Building.all, then actually lots of things happen:

1. Rails queries the DB (DB should have the 'buildings' table).
2. then the got from the DB request is "parsed" to a collection of Building instances.

So if you are looking for the same magic on Android to be available right out-of-the-box, then unfortunately this is not so. Instead, you should implement your own ORM and migrations approach. The starting point is the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).